# I have a 1993 GMC sierra 1500 and I have some questions about the grounding

Tags: electrical, gmc, sierra

When we bought the truck the original battery was grounded to the alternator and my dad told me I should remove the ground and put it to the frame. Well after we did that all of my gauges started freaking out and stuff and my truck would just die all of a sudden. So I re-grounded to my alternator and now it runs fine with no strange gauge happenings I'm afraid I'm still doing something wrong. What would it be of I am?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with grounding your battery to the bottom of the alternator, as that is where it is on most of these vehicles (may have come that way from the factory ... I believe my 91 Suburban was grounded there as well). The problem you encountered was there aren't enough grounds going to the body from the engine and wherever else to the body properly give a good connection to the gauges. It's one of the first things I check when all of my gauges start going funky at the same time with no other explicable reason. As long as you are charging the battery, your gauges are good, and you don't see any other problems, I don't think I'd worry about it being there.

As an aside ... my father once told me this: *If it ain't broke, don't fix it.* This seems like it's one of those cases.